# 100% visitors drop off after home

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I have a WP 3.3.2 site and i use the google analytics code.

Though everything seems ok with the results i get there is an error.
All visitors drop off after homepage.

You can check the image here.
! https://i.stack.imgur.com/QchMA.jpg

I change position of the GA code and from just before < / body> i moved it to just before < / head> and now i use a wordpress plugin for this work.

Still nothing changes.

Comment: First you don't need a plugin to handle that task, edit your footer.php file or whatever file outputs the </body> tag, second you need to place the code before the </body> tag to give a chance for the data to be collected properly

Comment: Thats where i had the code but nothing worked. So i moved it before </head> and still nothing and then i give a try to a wp plugin with the same result.

Answer (score 1):

From the look of things you don't have the code on all your pages or there is a serious problem with your homepage design.

Comment: I do have the code on all of my pages. I can't imagine what that problem could be :(

Comment: @t0s can you give me a link to your site please.

Comment: @t0s your tag is fine, could you add toomanyairmiles at gmail dot com as a viewer on your analytics and i'll take a look.

Comment: i'm not the admin. I will have to contact to the admin who is a friend of mine. I will email him to add you as soon as possible.

Comment: @t0s Ok let me know

Answer (score -1):

You will want to go into your `/wp-admin/` folder. Log-in and go to your `footer.php` file under *Appearance>Themes>Editor*. When you open the `footer.php` file you need to add the generated code to link to Google Analytics at the bottom of the source shown, this will ensure it is on every page. Then 'Save' your changes to the `footer.php` file.

Comment: NO! Do not put google analytics in the header! You will have to wait for GA to load before the page loads. Analytics tags should ALWAYS be the last thing on the page before the closing body tag.

Comment: @toomanyairmiles - I personally practice using it in the `footer.php` of WordPress sites, just before closing the `body` tag as well. I was a little tired when I wrote the original answer.

You are absolutely correct, Google Analytics will be forced to load if called before the `</head>` tag instead of the `body` tag. Thank you!

Comment: @toomanyairmiles - "You will have to wait for GA to load before the page loads." - No longer the case if using the [async snippet](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/asyncTracking).

Comment: @danlefree - Thank you for the information. Here is information for [migrating GA to Asynchronous](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/asyncMigrationExamples)!